# Laravel 5.7: Updated_at column when syncing existing pivot fields

Tags: laravel, pivot

Laravel 5.7 / MariaDB

I the current application we got 2 object, between them there is a relationship with a pivot table.

When I update the values, we use the default laravel function sync on the relationship. When I send the same values to the function in multiple requests, the updated_at is always updated. I was expecting it to be only updated when the pivot value has been changed.

Did I did something wrong? Or is this expected behavior.

Let me know if you need more info.

```
// relation
public function activities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
            Activity::class,
            'card_activity'
        )
        ->withPivot(['time'])
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
}

// sync data
Array
(
    [3fc3a434-a2ea-46f8-b512-7b2c79d3cf00] => Array
        (
            [time] => 1440
        )

    [9d2f2c16-7127-4f11-8122-9e22aa2675c9] => Array
        (
            [time] => 555
        )

)

// used function
$object->$relation()->sync($sync_data);
```

Comment: It's likely that `sync()` is simply calling a `SET updated_at = NOW()` function, which applies to all rows that it is updating, regardless of changed pivot table data or not. Are you explicitly relying on the value in `updated_at` for some other logic? Or is this more of an annoyance/inconvenience issue?

Comment: We are using the updated value from the sync response for a log. The value of this pivot is not changed, so should not be in the logging.

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately, this is the expected behaviour of `sync()`, it removes/adds all pivot data, so you might have to use a different method. There is `updateExistingPivot()`, which might work, but you'll have to manually handle `attach()` and `detach()` where required. This make this question quite broad though, and I'm not sure you'll get a concise answer.

Comment: Have you tried `syncWithoutDetaching()`? I'm not sure if it will work, but since it queries the existence of pivot relationships before saving it might.